# repast.simphony.ui.GUIScheduleRunner error message

Tags: repast-simphony

I'm a new user in RePast learning to run the mesoFON model. I get this error message. What is the problem?

I'm using Eclipse IDE 2018-09.

```
FATAL [Thread-5] 11:34:18,767 repast.simphony.ui.GUIScheduleRunner -   
RunTimeException when running the schedule  
Current tick (1.0)  

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.DynamicTargetAction.execute(DynamicTargetAction.java:72)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.DefaultAction.execute(DefaultAction.java:38)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduleGroup.executeList(ScheduleGroup.java:205)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.ScheduleGroup.execute(ScheduleGroup.java:231)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.Schedule.execute(Schedule.java:352)
    at repast.simphony.ui.GUIScheduleRunner$ScheduleLoopRunnable.run(GUIScheduleRunner.java:52)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at meso_FON.application.Environment$$FastClassByCGLIB$$fd509841.invoke(<generated>)
    at net.sf.cglib.reflect.FastMethod.invoke(FastMethod.java:53)
    at repast.simphony.engine.schedule.DynamicTargetAction.execute(DynamicTargetAction.java:69)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:781)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:518)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:448)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1749)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:177)
    at org.khelekore.prtree.MinMaxNodeGetter.<init>(MinMaxNodeGetter.java:29)
    at org.khelekore.prtree.LeafBuilder.getMM(LeafBuilder.java:69)
    at org.khelekore.prtree.LeafBuilder.buildLeafs(LeafBuilder.java:34)
    at org.khelekore.prtree.PRTree.load(PRTree.java:65)
    at meso_FON.application.Environment.getPRTree(Environment.java:423)
    at meso_FON.application.Environment.queryPRTree(Environment.java:234)
    ... 9 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is an issue with a mesoFOM specific-method call. I'd suggest reaching out to the mesoFOM model developers directly to see if they can help.